# Sending email reminder to user in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a schedule follow when the item is going to expiry in 3 months. I would like to send automated reminder to the owner of the item and the buyer.

However, every time I do a dynamic value in the Send email (v2) TO and CC, Power Automate create another apply to each, and then the follow does not work.

How to stop power automate from creation a new apply to each or if there is a way to solve this.

I have different contracts/ items owned by different people and buyer.

The Title is a single selection,

the owner/ buyer can be one or two selection.

Many thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apply to each is automatically created in case you want to use a item value from an array of items, than it needs to loop through all of them to return you your "email". In your case it might be b/c it will return you array of filtered items, then per each item you are asking for array of Recipients and also array of CC (Array because person fields are set to multichoice). Option 1 -  if you can, edit the SharePoint person fields to single-choice. Opion 2 - Create Variable of Recipient and CC before sending email (emails, delimeted by semicolon `;`)